# htaccess RewriteRule one parameter includes other

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I encountered an issue for the first time and have no clue why i am having this.
Below you see three lines of my .htaccess file. While `/urun/test-123` using `urundetay.php`, `/urunlerimiz/` have to use `urunlerimiz.php`. The issue is since 'urunlerimiz' include 'urun' inside of it, all of those three links are using `urundetay.php`.

```
RewriteRule ^urunlerimiz/?(.*)$ urunlerimiz.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^urun/?(.*)$ urundetay.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^urun-kategori/?(.*)$ urundetay.php [NC]
```

It works correctly when i set those parameters completely different. But i have to use it that way and i want to learn.
What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this problem in one of my project as well and here is how I resolved it:

```
RewriteRule ^urunlerimiz(/.*|)$ urunlerimiz.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^urun(/.*|)$ urundetay.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^urun-kategor(/.*|)$ urundetay.php [NC,L]
```

Trick is to append `(/.*|)` after every keyword.

e.g. for regex `^urun(/.*|)$` this will match `/urun` OR `/urun/` OR `/urun/foo` but will not be matching `/urunlerimiz` and `/urun-kategor`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use negative lookaheads in your pattern so that the string `lerimiz`  doesn't produce a match. As, accordingly to the [RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) the regex pattern used by `RewriteRule` is Perl compatible you should be able do it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^urun(?!lerimiz)/?(.*)$ urundetay.php [NC]
```